# Table row formatting when screen size is XS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I have a table that I want to try and format different if the screen size XS.

- If the screen size is SM or larger, I want everything on one line.
- If the screen size is XS, I want to have two lines per record.

The HTML below shows how I would format it from the server side if I knew the screen size.

When screen size SM or larger:

```
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>
```

When screen size is XS:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=3>Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>
```

When the screen size is XS, not everything fits properly on one line and I need to show all the information.  Is there a way using the bootstrap css to make this work?

Comment: Can you give us a more specific example. What about to give us an example with content in html and a draft about what result do you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not pot-committed to showing the information in a table (one that would break a lot of grid-like constraints anyway), then you can easily do this with the bootstrap grid system like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Description can get really really long.</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">Code</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">Category</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">Price</div>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/4ed1swp9/)